# Lily leaves are turning yellow, the old flowers have gone to seed. Advice on how to bring it back to health?

Tags: houseplants

[image] [image] my peace Lily with yellowing leaves . And what I can only assume are the flowers producing bulb's??

Comment: This is not a peace lily (Spathiphyllum) as such - can you describe what the flowers were like, or do you have an image of them? How long have you had the plant - and am I seeing variegated leaves (second picture) or is that just a trick of the light?

Comment: Lacking further data, this looks like some type of bulb, where often the foliage dies off after flowering, you need to cut WAY back on water while it sits dormant, and wait for it to sprout (and then flower) again.

Comment: It looked like a deep red peace lily I thought I was a hybrid I was given it as a present and not knowing much about it I just treated it like a lily thanks for your comments